# How make sort of backup for future

Tags: scala, playframework

This code looks for faculties and  compares it to received faculty from form.

If in DB it finds that faculty, than it adds this group to DB and after that  - redirects it, actually, to the same page, but in GET (this is POST method).

The problem is that I **need redirecting if it not added that group**. Maybe, someone knows how to make this simple and tidily?

```
def addGroup() = Action.async {
    implicit request =>
      GroupForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
        errorForm => ???,
        data => {
          (for {
            seqOfFaculties <- FacultyService.getAllFaculties
            future <- GroupService.addGroup(Group(0, data.nameGroup, data.faculty)) if seqOfFaculties.exists(_.name == data.faculty)
          } yield future).map(_ => Redirect(routes.GroupController.get()))
        })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
FacultyService.getAllFaculties.map { seqOfFaculties  =>
    if (seqOfFaculties.exists { _.name == "something" }) {
      Ok // or something else...
    } else {
      Redirect(routes.GroupController.get())
    }
}
```

You should be careful when using `if` statement inside a for-comprehension with `Future`s. You could get an exception... :) (with nothing that handles it)